# Remove Google Glass apk without having root access?

Tags: android, apk, google-glass

I was testing out the Glass quickstart and chose COMPASS to "re-upload" as a test (tutorial: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start#for_android_beginners)

Now that it worked, I'm stuck with 2x "Compass - sample" and can't call either one by voice commands.

[image: glass]

Compass isn't important to me but I am in the process of making an apps for the medical field and I would like to be able to remove it.

Is it possible to remove an .apk from Glass without rooting the device? I have Glass in debug mode and I'm capable of uploading apk's.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You've tried uninstalling the regular way over adb? `adb shell pm uninstall com.example.MyApp` (where `com.example.MyApp` is the package name defined in the manifest)

Comment: I'm pretty new to Android, could you link me to somewhere where this is explained? I have adb installed but I'm not sure how if running the command tells adb to do it on the Glass and not another device, I use the GUI ( droidAtScreen-1.0.2.jar ). i think you're leading me down the right track though

Comment: The [ADB Docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#commandsummary) detail it - just search for 'uninstall'. If you have more than one device/emulator connected, you can direct the command to a specific one via the `-d`, `-e` and `-s` commands - if you don't specify one, it won't run the command.

Comment: Please add it to answers so I can grant you credit. worked like a charm, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove it via the [standard way over ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#commandsummary):

```
adb shell pm uninstall com.example.MyApp
```

(where com.example.MyApp is the package name defined in the manifest).

If you have more than one device connected the command will fail - you can direct it to the only attached emulator via the `-e` flag, the only attached USB device via the `-d` flag, or a specific device via its serial number and the `-s` flag (serial numbers as listed in `adb devices`).